# Windows Server User Share Permissions

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, file-permissions

I've been attempting to setup the following on my new Windows Server AD setup:

`G:\Shares\_users` (`\\HS-W01\_users`) = Listable by `Domain Users`, modifiable by `Domain Admins`.

`G:\Shares\_users\%username%` (`\\HS-W01\_users\%username%`) = Full control by `%username, Domain Admins`.

I have Googled around and played with lots of settings... attempted remaking the share a few times but so far to no avail.

I can list files in `\\HS-W01\_users` from one of my clients, logged in as a `Domain User`. I can access my user directory. I cannot create files within my user directory (`\\HS-W01\_users\%username%`).

[_users permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSeUA.png)

[_users\%username% permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8FHF.png)

Comment: What's configured on the "Share" tab?

Comment: https://sysvoid.co/u/SysVoid_2016-05-23_10-44-27.png

Comment: And the share tab for `\_users\%username%`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If users don't have write permission on the parent share they don't have write permission on the subfolders.  You need to give Users Change permission on the share.

Useful blog post here discussing share and NTFS permissions: http://www.basvankaam.com/2013/06/15/share-vs-ntfs-permissions/

> When you create a shared folder you apply share permissions and NTFS
>   permissions (Read at a minimum) we’re clear on that. Next how do we
>   determine the effective permissions on the shared folder? Simply put,
>   you take the applied share + NTFS permissions and the most restrictive
>   of the two get applied. For example: if you grant User-A Read share
>   permissions and Full Control NTFS permissions, the most restrictive
>   one will come out on top which is Read. Meaning that the user, or
>   group of users, can’t create, delete or rename folders but just read
>   and browse through them. The opposite is also true, when you grant
>   User-A Read NTFS permissions and Full Control share permissions it’s
>   still the Read permission that gets applied as being the most
>   restrictive.

Comment: The top line of your answer solved it for me. Thanks!